# 3 different backgrounds with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if the following is possible with CSS.

I'd like there to be 3 horizontal bars running across the entire width of a background. Here's a rough mockup of what I would like the background to be [image]

I've been toying with the following but I can't seem to be able to position any of the backgrounds.

```
#blog {
width: 1200px;
height: 100%;
background-image: url("bg1.png"),
          url("bg2.png"), 
          url("bg3.png");
background-position: 10px 10px,
          170px 10px, 
          750px 10px;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5fo054L2/1/

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can only have one `background-image`. But you can combine them into one image :P Or use a gradient since it's just colors

Comment: darn it. liked your comment but can't unlike it. I forgot that you actually CAN have multiple background-images since css3.

Comment: CSS looks fine, please post some actual code (maybe a fiddle), so we can troubleshoot an actual problem

Comment: Whoops, forgot to add a jsfiddle! Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/5fo054L2/1/

Comment: @mango like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/qdf4n9dq/ or http://jsfiddle.net/jt853rs8/

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it. The issue is that you have the x and y position confused. Also, x position doesn't have any meaning if it repeats.

```css
.blog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/L3F9slr.png"), url("http://i.imgur.com/rmPDxMq.png"), url("http://i.imgur.com/9MMzDMs.png");
  background-position: 0px 170px, 0px 100px, 0px 10px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Here is an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5fo054L2/3/

Note that the vertical height (of text in your example) will limit the amount of the background images you see.

Comment: The fiddle is not displaying the backgrounds . . .

Comment: What browser are you using? The code is dependent on having a browser that supports CSS3. What do you see when you view the jsfiddle of the OP?

Comment: I use chrome 39 beta.  I'm seeing the text, but no BG at all.

Comment: Perhaps that is the issue. It works in the latest non-beta Chrome: 38.0.2125.104 m

Comment: Also, if your viewport is very wide, it's likely that the backgrounds won't render. You have to have enough vertical text to cover all of the background images.

Comment: Ok.  Still doesn't work w/ smaill viewport.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make three image files, place them below everything else, and set them using absolute positioning.